# "For Each cell In Range" loop works but does not fully perform unless run twice in a row?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I know its a bit of a mess, this is the first code I'm writing in VBA so I've got a lot to learn.

Essentially, the loop works as intended, where it checks if an employee ID exists across all 3 sheets, and if it doesn't it deletes that employee. However, it doesn't successfully delete every employee it should unless I run it twice. If I run it a third time, it doesn't delete any (which is correct).

I'm hoping to either figure out why it's not deleting on the first run through, or surround it in a while loop that counts the number of rows deleted and stops when none are.

I tried to make this code a second time with customer IDs and that one has to be run 7 times before it gets everything right, so whatever solution is found I'm hoping it'll work for that as well.

This is my code, as I mentioned there's probably a more streamlined way to do this, but I really just want to figure out what is causing it to have to run twice to catch everything within the criteria

```
Sub Part2()
'
' Part2 Macro
' delete employees that don't exist across all sheets
' doesn't delete everything unless I run it more than once (twice specifically)
' working on making a loop for the loop?
'

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Sheet1range As Range
    Dim Sheet2range As Range
    Set Sheet1range = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A25000")
    Set Sheet2range = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E2:E25000")
    
    For Each cell In Range("A2:A6000")
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(cell.Value, Sheet1range, Sheet1range, False) <> cell.Value Or Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(cell.Value, Sheet2range, Sheet2range, False), "000000") <> cell.Value Then
            cell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next cell
    
End Sub
```

Comment: When deleting rows, one must loop from the bottom up and not top down.  Change to the standard `For` loop using `Step -1`

Comment: Even better, create a range to delete using `Union` and only delete after looping.

Comment: Thank you! @ScottCraner 
So instead of 
For Each cell in Range("A2:A6000")
I should try
For Each cell in Range("A2:A6000") Step -1
Is that correct?

Comment: @BigBen if it's not too much trouble, could you give an example in this context?

Comment: Both linked threads demonstrate how to do this.